# Best and efficient way to extract a First word from string without space when only a "GOOD" string is available in string?

Tags: c++, string, performance

What is the best and efficient way to extract a **First word from string without space** when only a **"GOOD"** string is available in std::string

Example

**std::string temp = "  THIS IS MY STACK OVER FLOW SECOND QUESTION IS IT GOOD"
Output:THIS**

My below logic fails when only **"GOOD GOOD GOOD GOOD"** is available

```
#define SerachGOOD "GOOD"
#define SerachBAD "BAD "
#define firstpos 0
using namespace std;
void   removeSpaces(std::string & input)
{
        input.erase(std::remove(input.begin(),input.end(),' '),input.end());
        cout<<input<<endl;
}

void GetFirstiWord_IF_GOOD(std::string temp)
{
        if (temp.find(SerachGOOD)  != std::string::npos)
        {
                std::string FirstWord = temp.substr(firstpos, temp.find(SerachGOOD));

                removeSpaces(FirstWord);

                cout<<FirstWord<<endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is a "GOOD" string?  Also your string contains spaces but you say you want to do it without spaces.

Comment: Are you trying to get the first word (between spaces) of a string, if that string contains the word "GOOD"?

Comment: What would you want to print for `"GOOD GOOD GOOD GOOD"`? You only search for a word between the start of the string and the first "GOOD". This implies that you should print an empty string.

Comment: Why say:  using namespace std; when you later say std::string and std::remove?  Why not do the right thing and just use std::and whatever from there?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux first word GOOD

Comment: @NathanOliver yes "GOOD" is string if it is present  in my std::string then print first word i.e is THIS in above example

Comment: @MariosHadjimichael i am trying to get FIrst word only if "GOOD" is present in the std::string temp

Comment: @Drt yes sorry my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not trying to extract the first word at all.  It is simply removing all spaces from the input and then returning the remaining input as-is.

Thus, this input:

```
" THIS IS MY STACK OVER FLOW SECOND QUESTION IS IT GOOD"
```

Would output this:

```
"THISISMYSTACKOVERFLOWSECONDQUESTIONISITGOOD"
```

Which is not what you want.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define SearchGOOD "GOOD"

void GetFirstWord_IF_GOOD(const std::string &temp)
{
    if (temp.find(SearchGOOD) != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string::size_type start_pos = temp.find_first_not_of(" \t");

        std::string::size_type end_pos = temp.find_first_of(" \t", start_pos + 1);
        if (end_pos == std::string::npos)
            end_pos = temp.size();

        std::string FirstWord = temp.substr(start_pos, end_pos - start_pos);

        std::cout << FirstWord << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Or simpler, just let the STL do the parsing for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#define SearchGOOD "GOOD"

void GetFirstWord_IF_GOOD(const std::string &temp)
{
    if (temp.find(SearchGOOD) != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string FirstWord;

        std::istringstream iss(temp);
        iss >> FirstWord;

        std::cout << FirstWord << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but there is space when printing first word?
THIS  -- need this (no space)
    THIS -- but getting this ?

Comment: @ricky There is no space being output in either code example I gave above. This both output `"THIS"` by itself.

Comment: i am pass string from a file to your above function contain of file is 

<tab>        okok          GOOD      
<tab>        nono           GOOD
<tab >       yaya        GOOD


this is give me a tab space then output?

Comment: Tab and Space are two completely different characters. You did not say anything before about needing to handle tab characters. In the first example, you can simply add `\t` to the list of characters that `find_first_not_of()` searches for, and change the `find()` call to use `find_first_of()` instead. I have updated that example. In the second example, `std::istringstream` already handles tabs and space characters equally, so it doesn't need to be changed at all.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `std::stringstream` to read the first word from the string.

```
std::string GetFirstiWord_IF_GOOD(std::string temp)
{
    std::string FirstWord;

    if (temp.find(SerachGOOD)  != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::stringstream ss(temp);
        ss >> FirstWord;
    }
    return FirstWord;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/AaaXBN)

Comment: std::ifstream fin("file.txt");

        while (getline(fin, line))

        {
   cout<<GetFirstiWord_IF_GOOD(line)<<endl;
              }

i get blank space when called string passed from file

Comment: I added a demo, see the link.

Comment: @ricky: then you need to show the content of the file. This code works for the input you have provided so far, so clearly the file does not contain what you claim it to have.

Comment: this is working fine but cant accept this one since coz @RemyLebeau was the first to reply but thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a slight anomaly with your first string in that you have a leading space, that will throw off a simple parse (and in the case of your second example would appear to work correctly, but on a different string would have a completely different outcome).

e.g.: "THIS IS MY STACK OVER FLOW SECOND QUESTION IS IT GOOD"

vs: " THIS IS MY STACK OVER FLOW SECOND QUESTION IS IT GOOD"

To get around this issue, adding in an initial offset to the first word, then simply take everything up to the first space.  So, find, position, and split.

```
void GetFirstiWord_IF_GOOD(std::string temp)
{
    while (isspace(temp[0])) {
        temp.erase(0,1);
    }
    if (temp.find(SearchGOOD) != std::string::npos)
    {
        temp = temp.substr(0, temp.find_first_of(' '));
        cout << temp << endl;
    }
}
```

I think your remove string function is causing your false success in the first string, but I am having troubles running your code on my system.  If you drop the code above into your existing code it should work as you are expecting.

Comment: The `while` loop is a bit odd. You could just use something like `while ((offset < temp.size()) && (temp[offset] == ' ')) ++offset;` instead, or better just a single call to `temp.find_first_not_of()`. But more importantly, you are not subtracting the `offset` from the result of `find_first_of()`. The second parameter of `substr()` is a count, not an index.

Comment: Yeah, I am going to plead speed-slop.  The endless loop on a string without a space just makes it comically lazy.

Comment: I would still use `find_first_not_of()` instead of a loop at all: `size_t offset = temp.find_first_not_of(" ");`

Comment: Thank you for pushing it.  I have gotten very rusty in my old age.  I think I have a fix that is much cleaner, and actually more inline with how I like to think I think.

Comment: `while (isspace(temp[0]))` is not taking `temp.size()` into account, so the loop can go out of bounds. Why not replace the whole loop with a simple `temp.erase(0, temp.find_first_not_of(" \t"))`?

Comment: You beat me to it.  There have been quite a few changes since I last really wrote in C++, and some of the string functions are still quite new to me.  I still resort to some REALLY old stuff.  You can blame Arduino for me getting back into C++, and yeah, definitely clumsy. And isspace() actually takes care of it, EoS is null, and isspace must return false.